# Updating Backbone Model Attributes Dynamically

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js, attributes, models

I have a model that is part of a collection and retrieves data from the api. This model contains (among other attributes) the following attributes:

```
updatedDate //-> value retreived from API/DB
lastUpdateAttempt //-> value retrieved from API/DB
status //-> value NOT retrieved from API/DB, depends on values of above two attributes ("updated", "error", "out of date", etc...).
```

My question is, how can/when should I set the status attribute? Is there a way where I can dynamically set status when trying to retrieve the value? (i.e. modelObj.get("status") -> calls function to calculate value, returns result). Or should I call a function from the view to update this attribute on initialize, then add an event listener that does the same on change? (<-- somehow doesn't seem like the best solution)

I have a feeling I'm overthinking this and there is a really practical way of doing this, but I'm still a bit inexperienced with Backbone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the initial value of status, and listen for further changes to `updatedDate` or `lastUpdateAttempt` when the model is initialized.

Something like

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
     this.updateStatus();
     this.on("change:updatedDate change:lastUpdateAttempt",this.updateStatus);
  },
  updateStatus: function(){
   // your logic
  }
});
```

---

Or you can try this weird way (*not at all tested, just a thought*), which is somewhat like updating the status while accessing it. Might help if you want to control the frequency of status updates. (*if you are likely to access the status way less than the number of changes that is likely to occur with the other two properties*)

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
     this.updateStatus();
     this.on("updateStatus",this.updateStatus);
  },
  updateStatus: function(){
   // your logic
  }
});
```

and access the status like, `model.trigger('updateStatus').get('status')`

Comment: This worked! However, one issue i was still having was on fetch(), updateStatus() would not be called. So I added an "add" event listener to the collection that calls updateStatus()